# How can I sort an array with numeric and string values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

There is an array `[350, 456, "Not Found"]`. I want to sort it, and I want to get the lowest value(350). Could you help?

```
    var urunAdi = [350, 456, "NotFound"];
    urunAdi.sort(function(a,b){return a-b});
    var lowestPrice = urunAdi[0];
```

After sorting like this (350 - 456 - "NotFound"), I want it to find 350 as the lowest value.

Comment: You can do it with the following `.sort()` callback function: `(a,b)=>a-b||String(a).localeCompare(String(b))`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom function to `filter` the elements if they are `string` or number and return the [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) which basically merges these arrays.

```js
myArr = [456, 350, "Not Found"]

function sortMe(arr) {
  let numArr = arr.filter((el) => typeof el === "number").sort((a, b) => a - b);
  let strArr = arr.filter((el) => typeof el === "string").sort();
  return numArr.concat(strArr);
}

console.log(sortMe(myArr));
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done with a couple of Array methods:

```
const urunAdi = [350, 456, 'NotFound'];

const getLowestNumber = (arr) =>
  arr.filter((data) => typeof data === 'number').sort()[0];

const lowestPrice = getLowestNumber(urunAdi);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No worries my friend. Glad to help.